# Running an activity in android only once

Tags: android, android-activity

I've been working on an android app on eclipse ide. Everything is running fine, but i want the first activity to run only when the user runs the application fr the first time, and from then it should directly show the second activity.

I thought of solving this problem by creating a file when the application is run for the 1st time and from next time, if file exists, switch to second Activity. But, I would like to take a li'l assistance to know if there is any other better solution!?

Comment: Yes, using SharedPreferences. But basically it's the same concept: check if a variable is true/false (or if exists at all) - if so, close this activity and start the next one.

Comment: Okay, will google it up! 
Will be back if i dont understand :P

Comment: It's really easy to use the Shared Preferences. You won't need any further help. I'm sure.

Comment: ... just to make your search shorter: see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! 
found this link useful http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: It's a good site, I'll use it in the future, thanks for sharing!

Comment: It's done :) Working great!

Comment: Fantastic. I'm glad for you!